# Spring Boot Security how to check/verify access token

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am spring newbie

I've implemented OAuth2 implicit flow using spring security.
The question is how to check token validity? I've found `oauth/check_token` endpoint but first I wasn't able to reach it. Then I've made the following change:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception
{
    oauthServer.checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");
}
```

After the configuration I can use `check_token` endpoint but I wonder if it is correct to use `permitAll` on the endpoint. I've tried to change it to `isAuthenticated` but in that case I am not able to reach the endpoint because I don't store client_secret on my frontend app.

Should I continue use `permitAll` or there is better way?

Answer (score 3):

You should check access while using oAuth.

Try below code if works,

```
 @Override
    public void configure(
      AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) 
      throws Exception {
        oauthServer
          .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
          .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }
```

If doesn't, please share your security related snippets. Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks, it works, could you please explain what is difference between `tokenKeyAccess` and `checkTokenAccess`? And why this way is better then setting `checkTokenAccess` to `permitAll`?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Well, both tokenKeyAccess and checkTokenAccess applies to different entities.
isAuthenticated() is there to allow you to allow access for authenticated users regardless of what roles they have and permitAll() is there to allow all request from origins. 

Had already explained detailed stuff in my answer, sincere apologies for unknowingly discarding. :(